# How do I specify a gcloud csv format separator

Tags: gcloud

I am using `gcloud beta logging read` to read some logs and am using the `--format` option to format as csv:

`--format="csv(timestamp,jsonPayload.message)"`

which works fine.

[gcloud topic formats](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) suggests I can specify the separator for my CSV output (i'd like to specify ", " so that the entries are spaces out a little) but I can't figure out the syntax for specifying the separator. I've tried the following but neither are correct:

```
--format="csv(timestamp,jsonPayload.message),separator=', '"
--format="csv(timestamp,jsonPayload.message)" --separator=", "
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out.

`--format="csv[separator=', '](timestamp,jsonPayload.message)"`